# Python Finite Automata library

Tags: python, finite-automata

What would be the most complete finite automata library for Python, which is able to do the basic manipulations such as:

- Minimization,
- Determinization of Nondeterministic Finite automata
- Union, Intersection, and Product of the languages generated by these automata, etc.

All the libraries that I'm finding are either incomplete or do not work plug-and-play-wise.

Comment: Just native "sets" are doing union, intersection, ... :: http://docs.python.org/library/sets.html

Answer (score 3):

[`python-automata`](http://code.google.com/p/python-automata/) seems to be able to do all the things you're asking.

- What is it missing?
- Perhaps you'd want to contribute a missing feature yourself?

Comment: Missing a representation of nondeterministic finite automata, and a function to transform such NFA into a DFA. Its also missing a function to make homomorphisms: map an alphabet Sigma into a alphabet Sigma'. I would contribute myself if I am sure that there is no other library doing that already. Since all these operations are standard I believe somebody has already written such a library.

Comment: I suggest you add those requirements to your original post, then.

Comment: @asker Did you find a solution? If not, I would be happy to accept any contributions to python-automata.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using a underlying C++ library you could try [OpenFst](http://www.openfst.org%20OpenFst) with these [Python bindings](http://code.google.com/p/pyopenfst/%20Python%20bindings). 
[PyFsa](http://osteele.com/software/python/fsa/%20PyFSA) has the optimization algoritms you listed.